# DateFormatter issue in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to set date-formatter for the time **01/09/13 20:55:00+02:00**,

```
NSDateFormatter *departureFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[departureFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss+Z"];
NSDate *departureDate = [departureFormatter dateFromString:fullDateString];
```

but it's not succeeding.

Any pointers?

Comment: `@"dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"`

Comment: do not put `+` in formatter, it comes from time zone and it has to be dynamic.

Comment: Yeah, drop the `+` and use `ZZZZZ`.  `ZZZZZ` is a new form which can handle the embedded `:` in the timezone.

Answer (score -1):

You can use with below code :

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
[dateFormatter1 setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
NSDate *dateString = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:@"01/09/13 20:55:00+02:00"];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString.description);
```

You can get your deserve date.

Comment: You don't need to set the time zone for the date formatter if you are reading the time zone from the input string.